# Raspberry Pi B+ CPU clock manipulation

Tags: hardware, archlinux, cpu, system-clock

Is it possible to manipulate rPi B+ with ArchLinux system clock, I need to slow it down because of power management purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under and overclocking are possible the same way as for the older type B rev 1 and rev 2. Find the settings in `/boot/config.txt`, e.g.:

```
arm_freq=700
arm_freq_min=100
core_freq=250
core_freq_min=75
sdram_freq=400
over_voltage=0
```

Comment: This hint is superb, but what are "safe" values - down limits of these variables? I will not overclock it, but I need to keep the board running at lower frequencies because of power preservation reasons.

Comment: I am not sure, cos I just set those values on a rPi the other day. Maybe you'll find something useful at the forum at raspberrypi.org http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=32955 Presumably it's also possible to undervolt the device (but I didn't do that so I cannot recommend anything). With your B+ however a nice improvement should arise from the new power circuit.